# Oracle regexp match patterns in string that includes new line character

Tags: regex, oracle

I am trying to split string based on matching expressions. Please note this  includes newline characters.

Below is my query

```
with base aS(
      select 
      'sam s123 565 q2#
      nicole s1257 546 q4#
      mary s568 545' str1
      from dual
)
select regexp_substr(str1, '[^q[:digit:]]#+', 1, level, 'm') as split
  from base
  connect by level <= regexp_count(str1, '[^q[:digit:]]#+')
```

I want to see the rows returned as :

```
sam s123 565
nicole s1257 546 
mary s568
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change your regular expression to this.

```
(.?+) -- any one or more characters. Put this in brackets as first subexpression
q     -- letter q
\d+   -- one or more digits
#     -- character #
```

and include one more paraemter in REGEXP_SUBSTR function to extract only first subexpression. Use TRIM to remove blank spaces.

```
WITH base AS (SELECT 'sam s123 565 q2#
      nicole s1257 546 q4#
      mary s568 545' str1 FROM DUAL)
    SELECT TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (str1,
                                '(.?+)q\d+#',
                                1,
                                LEVEL,
                                'm',
                                1       --first subexpression
                               )
                )
              AS split
      FROM base
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (str1, '(.?+)q\d+#');
```

Output:

```
split
-------------
sam s123 565
nicole s1257 546
```

Since your third line doesn't have the matching pattern, it doesn't return that.

Comment: Thanks, but if the above mentioned string is not multiline, then this will not work. So, probably this needs to be put into a procedure.