# Oracle - regexp_replace to check beginning of each line in a string consisting of many lines

Tags: oracle, plsql, regexp-replace

I have a random string consisting of many lines and different number of characters in each line. I need to convert this string such that I have a fixed number of characters ,say 10, in each line. Also each of my new lines shouldn't start with a :

I tried :

`l_str:=replace(l_str,chr(10),'');` -- To first create a single long string 
:
I wrote the logic to divide the new long string to lines of 10 characters.
Now each line I used the

`l_str:=regexp_replace(l_str,'^:','/');`

And then I concatenated all the lines.

Can I first concatenate my entire string to one and then use the regexp_replace? 
Will it be possible to check the start of each line using regexp_replace itself?

Comment: It would help if you edited your original post to show a real example of the text you are working with, and an example of what it should like like after processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you set `match_parameter` to `'m'` (for multiline). More info is in the documentation about [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501).

See f.i. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457923/oracle-regexp-match-patterns-in-string-that-includes-new-line-character) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165274/regexp-replace-remove-new-line-n-from-string-only-if-is-enclosed-in-s).